# JSON - return number of items within a list that have a specific key value

Tags: javascript, json, object, hasownproperty

Having a bit of a nightmare trying to solve this JSON problem. I need to store the number of offers as a tally, but it needs to only be a number whereby the offers have an activated status. In the example below (simplified for illustration) the result should be 2 (as only only of them is false for the 'activated' key). I've tried to target it with this:

```
var count = Object.keys(object.allOffers[0].offers[0].activated.hasOwnProperty('true')).length;
```

^^^ but it returns 0. Furthermore it only selects the first offer and I need a method that will target all of the offers that sit inside allOffers. Any ideas? Sample code below.

```
object {
  "allOffers": [
    {
      "offers": [
        {
          "offerId": 15661,
          "activated": true,
          "viewed": false
        },
        {
          "offerId": 15641,
          "activated": false,
          "viewed": false
        },
        {
          "offerId": 16461,
          "activated": true,
          "viewed": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.offers[0]` only targets the first element in the array, and checking whether the `.activated` string has an own property of `'true'` doesn't make any sense.

Best method would be to use `.reduce` instead - iterate over the array, and add one to the accumulator for each object for which `obj.activated` is true.

```js
const input = {
  "allOffers": [
    {
      "offers": [
        {
          "offerId": 15661,
          "activated": true,
          "viewed": false
        },
        {
          "offerId": 15641,
          "activated": false,
          "viewed": false
        },
        {
          "offerId": 16461,
          "activated": true,
          "viewed": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

const totalActivated = input.allOffers[0].offers
  .reduce((a, obj) => a + obj.activated, 0);
console.log(totalActivated);
```

Filtering by those that are activated and then checking the length of the resulting array works too.

```js
const input = {
  "allOffers": [
    {
      "offers": [
        {
          "offerId": 15661,
          "activated": true,
          "viewed": false
        },
        {
          "offerId": 15641,
          "activated": false,
          "viewed": false
        },
        {
          "offerId": 16461,
          "activated": true,
          "viewed": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

const totalActivated = input.allOffers[0].offers
  .filter(obj => obj.activated)
  .length;
console.log(totalActivated);
```

Comment: Thank you kindly, this worked great. Bless you :)